# Como popular um bd .sql, que fica em um servidor, com php, ou java?

Tags: php, java, front-end

Tenho um bd na Hostinger, gostaria de desenvolver algo(pra daqui a 5 horas!!) que eu pudesse de diferentes máquinas popular esse bd, alguma alma caridosa pode me ajudar?

Comment: Desconheço o caso da Hostinger. Se estiver em servidores compartilhados ou VPS LIMITADOS isso não será possível facilmente. Entretanto o MySQL/MariaDB permite que outros servidores manipulem o banco de dados remotamente. Isso é útil caso possua "Failover", servidores redundates. Dessa forma você pode ter, por exemplo, 3 servidores de MySQL e 10 servidores de PHP. Todos os 10 servidores de PHP estão conectados nos mesmos 3 servidores de MySQL (que entre si é sincronizado). Ou seja, é possível facilmente permitir conectar ao MySQL de vários servidores. O MariaDB permite que limite o IP de acesso

Answer (score 1):

1- se vc quiser criar uma aplicação online, pode acessar de qq maquina e popular o banco via aplicacao.

2- pode acessar o banco via um programa de administracao de banco de dados por exemple e popular o banco também... remotamente ... sem ter criado uma aplicação...

tudo vai depender de como seria esse "popular o banco" e qual a finalidade ... se for para desenvolver a aplicacao eu faria com php mesmo ... cria a la a tabela e os campos de acordo com a sua necessidade ... 
servidor com com apache funcionando "php" criar uma conexão com o banco ... e ai vai depender de como vai passar as informacoes... se vai importar algum arquivo ou criar um formulário de acordo com as informações que precisa ...
posta mais informações

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Bem, eu gostaria de fazer uma aplicação(de preferencia web) pra que hoje, mais tarde, vários usuários pudessem acessa-la para popular um banco de dados sql, mas não sei nem por onde começar

Comment: quais as informacoes que vc quer guardar ?? primeira coisa criar um banco de dados um dos jeitos mais faceis... se la tiver e geralmente tem ... phpmyadmin... acessa.. se tiver que criar um usuario e senha cria la ... loga ... ai ja vai usar modo visual msm ... cria um banco de dados... ai depois conseguir criar uma tabela e criar os campos... lembar sempre de todas as tabelas deixar um campo id chave primaria auto increment... seleciona la... o resto  e se for texto escolhe la tipo de varchar pra texto e tamanho do campo ... ou int para numeros e tamanho do campo tb

Comment: O bd foi gerado a partir de um script gerado de um DER, e agora? os códigos me paracem bem extensos